# How to configure a optical fiber router modem to allow port forwarding with other connected router/or from main router itself?

Tags: networking, wireless-networking, router, wireless-router, port-forwarding

I recently got a new fibre connection, the ISP provided me with a wifi modem, although I have a router. Anyway back to the point, I was able to port forward with my old non-wifi modem and router set up
but now I can't port forward. I have searched the internet fully and I found almost the same situation like this one - [How to configure cable modem router to allow port forwarding to other connected router?](https://superuser.com/questions/724522/how-to-configure-cable-modem-router-to-allow-port-forwarding-to-other-connected)
But this also did not help me, I hope anyone would help me with this topic relatively soon. The manufacture of my modem is **GENEXIS**, Model of the router is Platinum-4410  and Router is **Archer A6(Tp-Link)**. Also, no my WAN IP address of router **does not match** my IP address from "What's my IP".

Comment: It sounds like you need to put the modem into bridge mode so it does not assign private IPs but rather assigns the external/public IP directly to an attached device. To confirm, you would need to see if the IP address assigned to your personal router's WAN interface is in the private IP range. This could also indicate that your provider is using CGNAT, in which case it is impossible to port forward). Please update your question with the manufacturer and model of your modem and router, and whether or not your router's WAN IP matches the result you would get from Googling "what's my IP".

Comment: Just to be clear, For me to know the IP address I should go to routers login in page and look for ipv4 address from netinfo (generally) right? Also btw I Have port forwarded Earlier before I received this wifi modem but with an older router(Tenda). I upgraded the router and wifi at the same time, so I am confused what's causing the problem.

Comment: Thanks for the info. If you have port forwarded before, then it sounds like this is just your modem assigning a private IP to the router. Are you able to reach 192.168.1.254 from a browser? That should be the modem's config page.

Comment: Yes, I can access it. And btw I port forwarded using my old router and modem. Now I Have both of them newer and different models.

Comment: OK, it should be as simple as placing the Genexis device into bridge mode.

Comment: I tried it, But when I place it in bridge mode the router(Tplink) show it has access to internet light, but I can't access the internet at all.

Comment: You are using the TP-Link router for Wi-Fi and not the Genexis, correct? You should disable Wi-Fi entirely on the Genexis device. The TP-Link router should run the Wi-Fi and everything else after the Genexis is in bridge mode.

Comment: Ya, I tried it like that, but not able to access the internet, When it is in bridge mode I completely get disconnected both wired and wireless.

Comment: Just to be clear, you have the Genexis -> TP-Link (WAN) -> Devices, and you have no devices connected directly to the Genexis? And you have restarted the TP-Link, and still have no internet?

Comment: ya,Genexis is connected to the router using Rj45 btw.Tp-link is LAN

Comment: it is like this, ISP>Genexis>Tp-link>Devices

Comment: Set Genexis to bridge mode, ensure Genexis plugs into TP-Link WAN port and TP-Link has DHCP on, restart TP-Link and any devices connected to it. Wait ~5 minutes. Do your devices get assigned an IP address?

Comment: Wait a sec,I'll try it and tell the result

Comment: Still no luck, And I noticed two different bridge mode.Ip bridge mode and PPPoE bridge mode, Does it affect anything, I have it now on PPPoE bridge mode.And I do get IP assigned to my devices

Comment: Sorry, I should have been more clear. You want to leave those settings alone. I am talking about a LAN setting. You want to disable NAT on the Genexis and switch to bridge mode on LAN so that the external IP is assigned directly to your TP-link router. I cannot find a manual for your device, so I can't give you more specific instructions.

Comment: Wait just to be clear I basically want to disable NAT on Genexis and switch Genexis to bridge mode right?

Comment: Do you need any additional information ?